# Active MQ performance

Tags: activemq-classic

I have a performance problem with active mq. I send small messages with a string of 20 characters. 
When I send 30.000 messages in, active mq gets very slow. I increase the memory now to 2GB before it was 1GB, now the performance is better.
My question is now, why does active mq needs so much memory for so small messages?

Comment: Without more detailed analysis it would be hard to offer any help, you need to describe the use case better and what your idea of poor vs good performance is.

Answer (score 0):

I would start my debugging with a thread dump and heap dump for activemq process id.. you can use jmap for heap dump analysis and samurai for thread dump analysis